# node.js app returns 'Cannot GET /' once deployed on CPanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel

the app displays and behaves perfectly on localhost but does not display at all once deployed on CPanel. I have deployed it on CPanel and run the command npm install from the GUI and I have run it also from the terminal using 'npm install -g npm-check-updates' followed by 'ncu -u'
I have tried to deploy the app the same way once more in case I made a mistake and get the same result. I don't understand why it does not seem to find 'app.get("/"'

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql"); // allow access to sql
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const VIEWS = path.join(__dirname, "views");
app.use(express.static("scripts"));
app.use(express.static("images"));
let index = 0;
var session = require("express-session");
var globalGallery = [];
let filter = false;
var lastSearchItem = "";
//var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "pug");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "-------",
  user: "------",
  password: "--------",
  database: "--------",
  port: 3306,
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log("db connected!");
  }
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let sql = "select * FROM photo ORDER BY photoId DESC; ";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, gallery) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    globalGallery = gallery;
    filter = false;
    res.render("index", {
      gallery: globalGallery,
    });
  });
});
```

**index.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
      .maincontent
          form(method="post" action="/filterphotos")
              input.search(name="search", type="text", Placeholder="type 'ir' for example...") 
              button.searchbutton(type="submit") Search     
          .grid-container
                each photo in gallery
                    - var text 
                    - text =  photo.photoPlace? photo.photoPlace : text
                    - text =  photo.photoCountry? text+" "+photo.photoCountry : text
                    - text =  photo.photoComments? text+" "+photo.photoComments : text 

                    a.div.tooltip(href='/displayphoto/'+photo.photoId)
                        
                  
 img.photothumbnail(src="http://isabellebidou.com/images/"+photo.photoThumbnail, alt=photo.photoThumbnail)
                        if text.length > 1 
                         span.tooltiptext #{text}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "isabellebidou.photos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "photo website",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "photoapp"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "constantinople": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGqHi.png)